# Looping through array to get Key with Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, loops, object

I would like to use Jquery to return the keys: Country, Country_Code and Continent and only have them showing up once.

```
 var countryList = [
          {"Country":"Canada","Country_Code":"CAN", "Continent":"North America"},
          {"Country":"USA","Country_Code":"USA","Continent":"North America"},
          {"Country":"Brazil","Country_Code":"BRA","Continent":"South America"},
          {"Country":"France","Country_Code":"FRA","Continent":"Europe"},
          {"Country":"Spain","Country_Code":"SPA","Continent":"Europe"}
 ];
```

How would I get return the actual key name without looping through the 5 objects Canada, USA, Brazil, France, and Spain in the countryList.

This is my code in jquery:

```
  $.each(countryList, function() {
     $.each(this, function(k, v) {
       console.log(k);
     });
  });
```

Thanks
Cheers

Comment: What language is this? You should add that as a part of the question and/or a tag. You should build a data structure that allows you access these directly instead of looping through them. Is there a reason this is an issue?

Comment: If you want to display the keys you just need to read the first array element and extract its keys.

Comment: (One presumes you've had enough sense to use an available kit to parse the JSON into objects in whatever language you're using.)

Comment: "without looping through the 5 objects" --- what is the technical requirement behind this limitation?

Comment: @Hot Licks: it actually is not a JSON, it's a JS array

Comment: @HotLicks

How would I read the first array element and extract in Jquery

Comment: But if the keys are identical in each, it should only be necessary to loop through one.

Comment: @Moxie C: you need to explain the original task, because your "read the first array element and extract in Jquery" doesn't make any sense

Comment: @zerkms - I said that.  And that's all that needs to be done, assuming all 5 array elements have the same form.  How it's done, I don't know.  I got into this before the OP admitted this was JS/JQuery, and I know nothing about JQuery and precious little about JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume the language we are talking about here is JavaScript.
In case all you want to get is the property name the below code should do, taking into consideration that all the objects in the array has the same set of them (otherwise you'll need to iterate them) just check the first one:

```
var result = []
for( var key in countryList[ 0 ] ) {
  result.push( key );
}
alert( result.join() )
```